# Guarded mixins to control color with LESS

Tags: css, less, mixins

My goal is to have dynamic text color on this poll http://tsn.thesn.net/poll/962 so that when there is no background color the text is dark gray, and when the green background is present the text is white.

Here are my styles for the background and text:

```
.chartlist .item { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 0.4em 4.5em 0.4em 0.5em;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: @grayDarker; 
}

.chartlist .index { 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  height: 100%; 
  background: @green; 
  text-indent: -9999px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  line-height: 2em;
 }
```

I've read the documentation for this on LESS but am having trouble visualizing how the syntax would work. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this:

```css
.colors(@col){
   color:@col;
}
.colors(@col,@bgcol){
   color:@col;
   background:@bgcol;
}
```

and then you could write:

```css
.chartlist .item { 
 /* ... */
  colors(@grayDarker); 
}
.chartlist .index { 
  /* ... */
  colors(white,@green);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still a bit confused at where the "when" statement comes in and how that works. Do you have any examples?

Comment: @mttwbsh I don't think you can use a `when` guard here, because you have to have the backgroundcolor stored somewhere in a variable. LESS can't check if you applied the background declaration somewhere in the codeblock. That's why i would just use the version with different parametercount as stated above.

Comment: This makes a little more sense. The problem is the width is coming from a percentage injected by PHP, so the style has to be dynamic. Does the above style solve this? Sorry for requesting so much clarification, I'm pretty new to LESS.